# How do I make my S3 videos viewable on specific website only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, protected

**UPDATE: Added CORS policy (below) and still it is not working. Please someone help me find the problem.**

I have been struggling with this for hours. I have a bucket called test-pcrp. I want the videos in this bucket to be viewable on my website only.  Below are the bucket settings, bucket policy and CORS that I have in place. However, no matter what I do the video is not viewable on the site.

**Bucket Settings:**
OFF - Block all public access
ON - Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
ON - Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
OFF - Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
OFF - Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies

**Policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.dev.pcrprograms.org and dev.pcrprograms.org.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-pcrp/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://dev.pcrprograms.org/*",
                        "http://dev.pcrprograms.org/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**CORS Policy**

```
[
{
"AllowedHeaders": [
"*"
],
"AllowedMethods": [
"GET",
"HEAD"
],
"AllowedOrigins": [
"https://dev.pcrprograms.org"
],
"ExposeHeaders": [],
"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
]
```

Comment: FYI your referer condition include `dev.pcrprograms.org` but not `www.dev.pcrprograms.org`. Which are you testing with?

Comment: The domain on the actual site does not include the www so that is the domain I am testing on.

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "not working". What is displayed within the Dev Console window in the web browser? What behaviour is shown in the Network window of the web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy probably isn't working because objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. Adding a `Deny` policy does not grant access -- it just further restricts access.

However, **using `referer` to control access is unreliable**. [Referer spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) is quite easy and should not be relied upon as a means of security.

The preferred option is to have your back-end generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which are time-limited URLs that provide temporary access to private objects stored in Amazon S3.

Comment: I am not worried about referer spoofing as this will live inside a membership area whose users do not have serious tech skills. This is also why I cannot use time-limited URLs. These videos will be available on the member site for the foreseeable future.

I updated my bucket policy but I still cannot view my videos on my website. Any suggestions on what I need to change to make this work?

Comment: The pre-signed URLs are generated by your backend system, and would not involve user skills. It's basically a way of saying "Okay, you are authorized to access this file, here's a link". I see you are using WordPress, so this could be done via PHP. See: [Presigned URL for AWS S3 Object with PHP](https://thecodebeast.com/post/presigned-url-for-aws-s3-object-with-php/73)

Comment: I would suggest debugging like this: First, remove the `referer` condition in the Bucket Policy. This should make the objects in the bucket accessible. Then, put back the condition and figure out what might be causing it to fail. Check any error messages in the Console output of your browser.

Comment: Ok the presigned URL is NOT working for me. Can someone please please help me sort out the reason the above bucket settings and policy is not working? The only error the console is showing is "np is null" and I cannot find any info on this.

Comment: Have you tested the code that generates the pre-signed URL? It should return a URL that you can put in a browser to retrieve the object.

Comment: Yes and that is not what i need. I need to be able to embed a video or audio file on a webpage in a membership site and this will not do that in a way that is playable on my site. Thus I just want to get the bucket policy to work.

Comment: I added the following CORS policy but still the video will not play on the specified domain. I am really desperate for some help here. I have Googled this to death and am not finding any help troubleshooting this.

I added the followig CORS policy and videos still will not play on the domain.

[
{
"AllowedHeaders": [
"*"
],
"AllowedMethods": [
"GET",
"HEAD"
],
"AllowedOrigins": [
"https://dev.pcrprograms.org"
],
"ExposeHeaders": [],
"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}
]

Comment: @JodieBurdette You’ve been told more than once you should use a signed URL. The signed URL is generated at the time the page is rendered. Or, if you want “proper” secure videos, actually encrypt the video and only allow playback through DRM.

Comment: @Martin Bean I have also explained why I cannot go that route and that I am putting his in a protected member site. I fully realize I am not using the preferred method. I am asking (begging really) for help getting the policy and cors settings setup correctly.

Comment: @JodieBurdette Yes. And if you use a signed URL, then you can keep your videos private and only logged-in users of your website will be able to view the video, as your application can authorise the user before generating the URL.